# Правильно ли я составил структуру бд по заданию?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql

Всем привет у меня есть задание:

> Создайте простую систему бронирования жилья (сам бэкэнд, не нужен
> фронт) . Основа:
>
> - квартиру можно снять на сутки (минимальное количество - 1 сутки)
> - одна квартира имеет в один момент Х свободных слотов т. е. может быть сдана в аренду для X людей одновременно (не обязательно с одним
>   бронированием что-то вроде общежития / размещения с возможностью
>   бронирования кроватей)
> - при бронировании более 7 дней мы предоставляем скидку X%
> - пользователь при бронировании определяет начальную, конечную дату и количество человек / кроватей.

Реализация будет на симфони, но думаю для моего вопроса это не важно.
По этому заданию у меня получилась такая структура бд:

```
user
id|email
```

Как сделать для кроватей/квартиры? К таблице `user_appartament` добавить поле `beds` и при выборе целой квартиры вставлять сюда количество слотов с сущности `appartament`? Или лучше добавить ещё одно булево поле `full` в которой буду обозначать, что будет снята вся квартира?
Если есть лучшее предложение по структуре бд или название таблиц, то прошу предлагать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть несколько мелких замечаний, а в целом - годится.

1. `user_appartment` я бы переименовал в `reservation` - ведь это то, что по сути представляет собой запись в этой таблице
2. смысла добавлять поля `full` или `beds` нет, если поле `guests` уже хранит количество зарезервированных данной резервацией мест. Это производные поля, которые денормализуют данные без особой на то необходимости. Количество свободных мест в квартире всегда известно: это разница между `apparment.slots` и `sum(reservation.guests)` для всех резерваций данной квартиры.
3. Точно так же нет смысла хранить производное поле `discount`. Оно однозначно определяется на основе полей `start_date`, `end_date`.

Comment: спасибо, с 1 и 3 согласен. А на счёт второго, а как тогда определить сколько ещё свободных мест осталось в квартире? По заданию в ней могут сдаваться отдельные комнаты, как тогда записать сколько кроватей заказал полтьзователь и сколько ещё осталось свободных?

Comment: спасибо, попробую сделать как вы подсказали